# Relation between intrinsic magnetic moment and moving charges

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, magnetic-moment

Moving charges creates magnetic field which is relativistic effect of electric field but magnetic field is also created by the intrinsic magnetic moment. How are they related? How does intrinsic magnetic moment exerts force on moving charges?

Answer (score 0):

The intrinsic magnetic moment of an electron acts in exactly the same way as the orbital magnetic moment. Taking its rotation produces a current that is the source of a vector potential, of which the rotation is the magnetic field.

Comment: But electron has spin doesn't mean that electron is spinning like a gyro. Could you please explain what do you mean by vector potential?

Comment: "But electron has spin doesn't mean that electron is spinning like a gyro." A) why not B) my argument does not rely on a mechanical model of electron spin. "Vector potential" Its rotation is the magnetic field. Google: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_potential